# Why im getting an infinite loop and how could i solve it?

Tags: loops, infinite-loop

Im pretty new to programming so i probably made lots of mistakes helllpppp

Im writing a program where user should enter number of integers , then the program should print out how many even numbers are there in those integers and there sum

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int n=3;
    int counteven;
    int count=1;
    int sum=0;
    cout<<"Enter the number of integers: ";
    cin>>n;
    while(count<=n)

        cin>>n;
        count++;
        if (n%2==0);
        { 
        counteven;
        sum=sum+n;

        cout<<"The even numbers are:"<<counteven<<endl;
        cout<<"The sum of eve numbers is:"<<sum<<endl;}
        system("pause");
        return 0;
        }
```

thankss

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have any braces ({}) for your while loop which is probably causing it to loop over the line:

```
while(count<=n)
```

An example of a correct while loop (taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/)):

```
// custom countdown using while
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int n = 10;
  while (n>0) {
    cout << n << ", ";
    --n;
  }
  cout << "liftoff!\n";
}
```

Comment: Well spotted, I was really scratching my head over that one! Strangely passing a char into cin caused the loop to break. I'm generally a PHP programmer so there's probably a simple explanation to that!

Comment: It looks like the program expects n to be an integer and many of the operations used (n%2 = 0 or count<=n) would break or not function properly if n was a char.

Comment: ohh thanks alott i also had to initialize counteven but the program isn't working :( is there anything wrong in this code ? really appreciating the help !

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with it, but the largest problem is that you are resetting the value of 'n' every time the user enters a number. You want to set it once at the beginning then set (and therefore check) a DIFFERENT value inside of the while loop. Start by fixing that and the rest of the issues will become A LOT easier to figure out.